# How to solve System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() Exception

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, exception, ado

I have a C# application who read in an SQL Server Database.
Sometimes i get an error and the apps crash.

If i look on the EventViewer, i got this :

```
Application : XXXXXXXXX_CLI.EXE
Version du Framework : v4.0.30319
Description : le processus a été arrêté en raison d'une exception non gérée.
Informations sur l'exception : System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception

Informations sur l'exception : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
   à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException, Boolean, System.Action`1<System.Action>)
   à System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject, Boolean, Boolean)
   à System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(System.Data.SqlClient.RunBehavior, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader, System.Data.SqlClient.BulkCopySimpleResultSet, System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject, Boolean ByRef)
   à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader, System.Data.SqlClient.RunBehavior, System.String)
   à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(System.Data.CommandBehavior, System.Data.SqlClient.RunBehavior, Boolean, Boolean, Int32, System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef, Boolean, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader, Boolean)
   à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior, System.Data.SqlClient.RunBehavior, Boolean, System.String, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1<System.Object>, Int32, System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef, Boolean)
   à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior, System.Data.SqlClient.RunBehavior, Boolean, System.String)
   à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior, System.String)
   à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
   à XXXXXXXXX_CLI.Program._RG_1(System.String, System.String, System.String, System.Data.DataRow, System.String ByRef, System.String ByRef)
   à XXXXXXXXX_CLI.Program._Fct_01(System.String)
   à XXXXXXXXX_CLI.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

Is a connection problem ? or a parsing problem ( we can see :

> System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()

)

Thanks a lot,

regards,

Comment: Almost certainly a network issue.

Comment: It surely raises an error trying to execute a SQL command, there could be many reasons, wrong data, connection problems... You should add exception handling code to locate the problematic line or lines and the exact exception error message, which would be far more descriptive that "The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception"

Comment: edit, i add new error message

Comment: Can you post your SQL connection string (with sensitive details, like the password redacted)? I'm wondering whether there's something invalid in it while it's being parsed prior to opening the connection.

Comment: @AlexK., it should be the permanent, not related to query, not related to state of code, not related to state of net etc. error. Almost certainly you're not right ;-)

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni, in my case an exeception is not raised. The EF method is processed without an catchable error, I can deal with it only on the following code, parsing the result.

Comment: @MartinCostello, there was no special in my connection string. Server (tested with name and with IP address), database, login, password.

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni, did you find any helpful? I've found only this GitHub issue, which contains no advice useful for me: https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/365 but I have no chance to update SqlClient soon.

Comment: You need to get the `.Message` property from the exception at the time when it's thrown. You can't do that looking in the Windows event log. You need to be able to edit the program in Visual Studio (or similar) to check it there.

Answer (score 0):

Had 2 days of work on this issue.

Everything was working for me on Development Environment but was throwing this exception on the Test Env.

I did two things at the same time, on the same pull request So I'm not too sure which one fixed this but you could check/resolve both.

My first guess on what fixed it, is that I've updated to the latest version of System.Data.SqlClient.
Second, I had a .NetStandard 2.0 project in my solution. I've removed it.

Comment: I am fighting with this issue more than a week, in 2020, with System.Data.SqlClient from last updates, so you are the happy guy, @Victor.