# Tools to log error on C# for SqlClient Exception

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio, sqlexception

I have a c# application which do some select in an sql server database.
I use the SqlClient functions from the .net framework.

The application run at night and sometimes the application crash :

```
Application : XXXXX.EXE
Version du Framework : v4.0.30319
Description : le processus a été arrêté en raison d'une exception non gérée.
Informations sur l'exception : System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception

Informations sur l'exception : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
   à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException, Boolean, System.Action`1<System.Action>)
   à System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject, Boolean, Boolean)
   à System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(System.Data.SqlClient.RunBehavior, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader, System.Data.SqlClient.BulkCopySimpleResultSet, System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject, Boolean ByRef)
   à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader, System.Data.SqlClient.RunBehavior, System.String)
   à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(System.Data.CommandBehavior, System.Data.SqlClient.RunBehavior, Boolean, Boolean, Int32, System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef, Boolean, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader, Boolean)
   à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior, System.Data.SqlClient.RunBehavior, Boolean, System.String, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1<System.Object>, Int32, System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef, Boolean)
   à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior, System.Data.SqlClient.RunBehavior, Boolean, System.String)
   à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior, System.String)
   à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
   à XXXXX.Program.Fct01(System.String, System.String, System.String, System.Data.DataRow, System.String ByRef, System.String ByRef)
   à XXXXX.Program.Gestion_Articles(System.String)
   à XXXXX.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

The error does not occur on each run.
I have some diffuclties to find the problem, when i run in debug mode, all is fine...

I wonder if it exist a tool or a way to get some additionnal informations about this crash.

Comment: Can you share the code for this function call?

Comment: Well...the message is "the process was terminated due to an unhandled exception". perhaps you should add a try catch so you can see the actual error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43475996/how-to-solve-system-data-sqlclient-tdsparser-throwexceptionandwarning-exceptio

Comment: Do what Sean said in "XXXXX.Program.Fct01(System.String, System.String, System.String, ..."

Comment: Does the DB happen to do Backups / index refresh overnight?

Comment: @Fildor Yes but at the crash time, the tasks are done.

Comment: @Amit The function is heavy

Answer (score 3):

Wrap it with a try/catch, then log the message and the innerException, and the task your trying to do with sql.

You can also use something like log4net (nuget package) to log the error but that's not really the issue.